# Удалить файлы в андроиде

Tags: android-adb, android

Я захожу на андроид через консоль и adb. В одной из директорий лежит папка с файлами и под папками. Удалить эту папку командой rm не получается, а по одному файлу удалять не радует. Как удалить всю папку целиком используя консоль и adb? OC Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm -r /путь/к/каталогу
```

Должно работать. Это рекурсивное удаление всего содержимого директории и самой директории

Comment: Да, получилось. Я делал по привычке rm -rf :(.

Comment: rm -rf это rm -r --force. -f точно не уменьшит шанс на удаление. Вы что-то путаете..

Comment: Просто, как я понял, там нет опции -f.